# Alternative to wildcard searching for multiple criteria; vba-excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with ~50k rows; one of the columns has a description.  I want to filter the description column using multiple wildcards.  That is apparently a gamebreaker in Excel.  I used a code similar to the following and the end result was individually sorting per each criteria:

```
Sub Product_Sort()

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$47853").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
Array("=*ProductA*", "=*ProductB*", "=*ProductC*", "=*ProductD*"), Operator:=xlOr

End Sub
```

In the end, there are 87 wildcard criteria that need to be searched.

I think I've thought of an alternative... to use the existing sort filters, and for each search in the array to add an "x" to the End(xlToRight) +1 column.  The problem is I do not know enough about loops to make that work.

Is anyone able to help me sort out this mess?  Additionally, if there is another alternative to this process, it would be appreciated for you to enlighten me.

---

Edit 20150825, 08:21CDT

The data I'm working with have large strings which may contain the term to match., e.g.1 The issue with ProductA is the widget, e.g.2 ProductC has pants, or e.g.3 Someone threw out ProductF.  There are ~50k rows with entries like this in my data.

In the above examples, and based on the initial code, I am searching only for ProductA, ProductB, ProductC, and ProductD; this would give a result matching the wildcard for e.g.1 and e.g.2 only, with possibly #N/A or #Value for e.g.3.

In trying sums, matches, and vlookups, I cannot seem to find a way for the individual terms to be the wildcards (e.g. ProductC) in my array. I have tried a VLookUp similar to this: =vlookup("*" & Sheet1! A$1:A$38 & "*", J2,0,False) which... honestly gave me inconsistent information.  I had hits in places they shouldn't have been.

Hopefully that adds some more info to the issue.

I tried using http://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?270-vLookup-with-wildcards-%28equivalent-of-quot-contains-quot-%29-best-solution and can't seem to get the sum/iferror string to pan out for me.

Comment: I think you could create a worksheet with one column of all your filters, then create a helper column with a lookup formula that references that column. Then just filter off of that.

Comment: I'm trying and can't seem to get it to work.  Let me try to post an example of the data in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your wildcards in a column on another sheet and use this formula:

```
=LARGE(IFERROR(MATCH("*"&Sheet2!A$1:A$4&"*",A2,0),0),1)
```

Confirm as an array formula with ctrl+shift+enter. 1 means its a match, 0 means it did not match.

Sheet2!A$1:A$4 is the range containing your wildcards, and A2 is the current cell with the string you want to check. You can autofill down to the rest of your column.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting straight zeroes.  Not familiar with Large so trying to understand what's going on before I move forward.  Right now, when utilizing my sheet:  =LARGE(IFERROR(MATCH("*" & Sheet1!A$1:A$38 & "*",J2,0),0),1)   The spreadsheet is an export and autonamed the sheet, so my 'addition' with the wildcard list is on Sheet1.

Comment: I think part of the issue is that the match has a lookup value of the array and it's trying to match to my value.  I changed the order to see if it would help at it looks like this: =LARGE(IFERROR(MATCH('query_export_results(1)'!J2,"*"&Sheet1!A$1:A$38&"*",0),3),1)   The large function appears to work on its own, but I'm having issues with the IfError part.  I did a check by changing the value for IfError to 3 and it shows up across the board, when previously it listed 0, which is also if there is no match.  Trying to figure out what the error with IfError is, atm.

Comment: The original formula is correct. You need to put an `*` in between both instances of `""` in the `MATCH` portion.

Comment: Also, `LARGE` is very simple to understand, in case you're interested. Given a set of numbers, it simply returns the kth highest number. I only use it here as a hack, along with `IFERROR` to get rid of the error values.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  The asterisks are disappearing when i paste my script in.  I'm testing on a row that has the value i want to find embedded within the cell.  I cannot get the match to return a value indicating the script sees the specific term being looked for.  I tried with the array, now I'm trying with the specific word.

Comment: ...and just got it!!!  Thank you!  I put single apostrophes around the Sheet1! making it 'Sheet1'! and it worked to get the match done; I also got it to work without the Large being used.  It's the stupid little things... much appreciated, Kyle!

Comment: Doh... I thought I was good.  Just went to replicate my activity and I'm failing to get all values from the array to show up.  Only the first value in the array is being marked as "1".

Comment: @Cyril You have to use LARGE(). LARGE() handles the array that the IFERROR/MATCH combination returns. Without it Excel will only look at the first row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87916/discussion-between-cyril-and-kyle).

Comment: Hey and sorry about that. Had gotten excited that it worked without; went back in, attempted to redo it and errorred out. I am currently using ` =LARGE(IFERROR(MATCH(""&Sheet2!A$2:A$39&"",J2,3),3),1) ` and getting a list of hits, most of which do not contain any of the words in the array.

Comment: Fixed it.  Thanks, Kyle!  The issue I was getting appears to have been generated by the ctrl+shift+enter.  On some cells, it was giving me a pop-up to select the spreadsheet, and on others it was not.  Once I closed and re-opened the workbook, when I checked the array, it gave me the pop-up and it worked.  Sorry for the extra inquiries and thank you much for sticking with me on this.